# What file is in every unix login?

Tags: unix-shell

I was asked that question and to be honest not sure if I understood that. I would say shell but instead of shell we can run any other program so ...

any idea by unix gurus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be

```
/bin/login
```

Comment: sounds good to me ...